# Probability Poker Question

Tags: probability, poker

You are dealt $20$ cards. What is the probability you have all kings given that you hold at least one king?

So I set it up like 
$$
P(4\textrm{ Kings | at least one king}) =\frac{{4 \choose 4}{48 \choose 9}}{{52 \choose 20}-{48 \choose 20}}
$$
Does this setup look correct?

Comment: Where does $\binom{48}{9}$ come from? If you replace with $\binom{48}{16}$ as @Alex then it looks correct.

Comment: Yea I was abe to catch my mistake on that one. Its just 20-4. Duh.

Answer (score 1):

$P(4 \text{ Kings | At least one King})=\frac{P(4 \text{ Kings and at least one King})}{P(\text{At least one King})}$

Now $P(4 \text{ Kings})=\frac{\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{16}}{\binom{52}{20}}$ and $P(\text{At least one King})=1-P(\text{no King})=1-\frac{\binom{48}{20}}{\binom{52}{20}}$

So your final answer is $$\frac{\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{16}}{\binom{52}{20}-\binom{48}{20}}$$